# Angular 2 build error - '../@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' no exported member 'bootstrap'

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap

I'm getting an error where TypeScript is not recognizing the exported 'bootstrap' function from platform-browser-dynamic.

```
ERROR in [default] ../retain-app/src/main.ts:1:9 
Module '"../retain-app/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index"' has no exported member 'bootstrap'.
```

I imported bootstrap in main.ts like so:

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
```

This is the dependency in the package.json:

```
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0",
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bootstrapping is done a little different with the final version, as opposed to some earlier RCs/betas. We no longer use `bootstrap`. You should instead import the function `platforBrowserDynamic`, and load the app module with that function

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './your.app.module.location';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

If you are going off an older tutorial that's not using modules, you may want to just check out the [Angular Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). At least the second half (after all the environment setup) where it shows how to use a module.